# Set Scheduled Task with PowerShell Script on Remote Computers

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, remote-desktop

I am trying to create powershell script (new to PS) for setting up a schedule 
task entry, to run a bat file.

**Entry point:** reading the computer names from a security group in AD, then export the list of computers to a .csv file.

**What to process?** run a .bat file which is already copied to the remote computers C:\tmp\file.bat

**What's the ask**I believe I can set the job, but if the job already existed on the remote computer, I cannot handle the error/catch. I would appreciate it if someone helps me. Thanks for your time!

```
Function set-TaskSchedule {
  $RPCs = Get-Content ".\List.csv"
  foreach ($item in $RPCs) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $item {Register-ScheduledJob -Name DumpLogs -ScriptBlock {Start-Process C:\tmp\file.bat} -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm)}
    Write-Host "$item is set!"
  }
}
set-TaskSchedule
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using try catch blocks to catch the errors or exceptions, below function should help u with that

```
function set-TaskSchedule
{
Param($xyz) #ifany parameters for input to function
try
{
    $RPCs = Get-Content ".\List.csv"
    foreach ($item in $RPCs) 
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $item {Register -scheduledJob -Name DumpLogs -ScriptBlock {Start-Process C:\tmp\file.bat} -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm)}
        Write-Host "$item is set!"
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Error " Exception while scheduling task"
    Write-Error $_.Exception.message
    Write-Error " ErrorStack: $Error[0] "
    #exit 1
}
return $abc #if u want to return anything form this function
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to write a try-catch the easiest option is to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to your `Register-ScheduledJob` command.  I would recommend extensive testing and make sure that suits all scenarios.  If not you should take the time to write an error handler.  You can have multiple lines in the scriptblock and adding line breaks will make it easier to read.

Here is an example of using Try-Catch within your Invoke-Command:

```
Function set-TaskSchedule {
  $RPCs = Get-Content ".\List.csv"
  foreach ($item in $RPCs) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $item {Register-ScheduledJob -Name DumpLogs -ScriptBlock {
      try {
        Start-Process C:\tmp\file.bat -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -Daily -At 05:30pm) -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "$item is set!"
      }
      catch {
        Write-Host "$item failed!"            
      }
    }
  }
}
set-TaskSchedule
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint!
How can I do this with try-catch? Sorry, like I mentioned, new to PS and learning..

Comment: Ram shows the use of a Try-Catch below, but it won't work because Invoke-Command doesn't pass exceptions back to the caller.  I'll update my answer with Try-Catch example

Comment: Thanks for the update, but when I paste your try-catch code to PS-ISE, it said you are missing the catch portion. I guess we need a bit of formatting.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting is kind of weird, still getting used to it. I had copied part of your code to make the example look more like what you were doing and there was an errant ‘}’. I have removed it from the example.